# My for loop stops after I ask for a user input

Tags: java

The user adds information about a person and stores it in an array list which is written to a file. The information is an ID number, first and last name, title and year of birth. When I use a for loop for the user's inputs my program asks for the ID number, and after the input, stops. The run doesn't stop, it just does not ask for the rest of the inputs.
I've tried multiple different ways to get input from the user, including most recently the while loop.
Any tips on what I can do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PersonGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <String> recs = new ArrayList<>();
        File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        Path file = Paths.get(workingDirectory.getPath() + "\\src\\PersonTestData.txt");
        String idNum = "";
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        String title = "";
        String YOB = "";
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
            SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter the ID Number: ");
            while (in.hasNext()){
                recs.add(in.next());
            }
            SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter the first name: ");
            SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter the last name: ");
            SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter their title: ");
            SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter the YOB: ");
            SafeInput.getYNConfirm(in, "Do you have more people to add?");
            recs.add(idNum);
            recs.add(firstName);
            recs.add(lastName);
            recs.add(title);
            recs.add(YOB);
        }

        try
        {
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
            for (String rec : recs)
            {
                writer.write(rec, 0, rec.length());
                writer.newLine();
            }
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Data file written");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `while (in.hasNext()){ recs.add(in.next()); }` is going to add an indefinite number of ID numbers. You have no terminating condition except ALL input. Does `SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter the ID Number: ");` perhaps **`return`** something?

Comment: Learn to use the debugger, and step through the code. Also, don't ignore the exception, let it be thrown from your main method by removing the try/catch block.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The safeinput code there is a method that allows input only if the string has a value. If the string doesn't have a value it asks the user to enter a value instead of nothing. I'm trying to store this data in an array list and print it to a file.

Comment: @reedaleson Elliot's inquiry about whether SafeInput returns something suggests that your code should look something like, `recs.add(SafeInput.getNonZeroLenString(in, "Enter the ID Number: "));`